# Reset Password in django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am following a blog to reset the password in django. It states to add :

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'  # During development only
```

in settings.py file.

But I want to deploy my web application in production. So what steps should I take care about?  Will this tutorial is safe for the production too?

The blog link is given below:

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the django documentation and the checklist for production deploy to be on the safer side. And as far as the [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/) goes, it is a very well explained  blog for learning about django.

[Django Production Deployment checklist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/)

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned in tutorial it is only for **`Development`**. But when you move to **prodution** you need to configure it properly based on your `SMTP` type. I'll specify it all here:

**For production (DEBUG=False)**

```
SMTP Email-    EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
Server    -    EMAIL_HOST=127.0.0.1
(Standard)-    EMAIL_PORT=25
               EMAIL_HOST_USER=<smtp_user>
               EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD=<smtp_user_pwd>
```

- If the SMTP email server is running on a network or a different port than the default, adjust EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_PORT accordingly.
- In today's email spam infested Internet, nearly all SMTP email servers require authentication to send email. If your SMTP server doesn't require authentication you can omit EMAIL_HOST_USER and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD.

---

**Django email configuration for Gmail or Google Apps account**

This is all you need to set up a default email connection to Gmail or Google Apps in Django.
In your `settings.py` use this code with your credentials:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT=587
EMAIL_HOST_USER='username@gmail.com/OR/username@coffeehouse.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='password'
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
```

Comment: Sir @ans2human should I add EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
in my development phase and when I move to production, I will add email backend host port according to your instruction in settings.py file. is it fine?

Comment: yes brother, for the developement part you play around with the settings given by **Vitor**, when moving to production use these configurations.

Comment: @imsaiful, but you can still try these settings just to check they work and then you may support this answers for accepting it, which will work as a reference point for people having same query.

Comment: Ok Sir @ans2human thank you so much. I am developing an application for my society. I will need your help again when I will deploy this on AWS ec2

Comment: for Aws the settings differ, so drop a comment when you need those settings, i will update the answer.

Comment: Sir  @ans2human my development phase is about to compete. So you can add those settings.